# Unpermitted parameter: ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ror and when I submit my form:

```
<%= form_for :project, url: projects_path, html: {id:'form'} do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :text, placeholder: 'Новая задача'  %> 

    <%= link_to  'Отмена', '', id:'cancel_link' %>
    <%= link_to  'Отправить', projects_path, id:'submit_link' %>

<% end %>
```

Have error:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OR2HWCi3zVz9gB5VAmnzbEuzIwFGE58JlLrWQdNcws6FVTzqh5Cu0zvUJTUEv2O/sCvU9HuadJYr3mfA40ehGA==", "project"=>{"text"=>"NEW ITEM"}} Unpermitted parameter: :text
```

Have two models:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :todos
 validates :title, presence: true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos
end


class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, required: false
end
```

The Todo model has a text attribute in which our todo should be located

Controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @projects = Project.all
end

def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def update
end

private 
    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:title, todos_attributes: [:id, :text])
    end
end
```

Project db

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
 create_table :projects do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.string :todos

  t.timestamps
end
```

Todo db

```
 class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
   create_table :todos do |t|
     t.text :text
     t.boolean :isCompleted
     t.integer :project_id

     t.timestamps
end
```

I'm requesting the todo attributes using accepts_nested_attributes_for: todos, the controller is also registered on the guides, in project_params I request todos_attributes. But when sending a form to the database, the value is text. He does not save in db. Can u help please

Comment: change `:text` to `:title` => `f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Новая задача'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save `text` field in `Todo` model, you have to create nested form. Use `nested_form` gem for this purpose.

A vague example to show how it works:

```
<%= nested_form_for :project, url: projects_path, html: { id: 'form' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Новая задача' %>

  <%= f.fields_for :todos do |todo_form| %>
    <%= todo_form.text_field :text %>
    <%= todo_form.link_to_remove "Remove this todo" %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a todo", :todos %></p>

  <%= link_to  'Отмена', '', id:'cancel_link' %>
  <%= link_to  'Отправить', projects_path, id:'submit_link' %>
<% end %>
```

In controller, to have the functionality of removing a todo in case of editing a project:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, todos_attributes: [:id, :text, _destroy])
end
```

In the migration `CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`, I do not think that you require `todos` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

The form which you created is wrong, you need to create a `nestead_form`

It is giving you and `Unpermitted parameter` error because the `text` is not a field of project model you can check this on your migration file. You need to change it to `title` because the `title` is the field of project model.

And for to create a nested form you need to do some changes in your form

```
<%= form_for :project, url: projects_path, html: {id:'form'} do |f| %>

   <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Новая задача'  %> 
   <%= f.fields_for :todos do |todo| %>
      <%= f.text_field :text %>
   <% end %>

   <%= link_to  'Отмена', '', id:'cancel_link' %>
   <%= link_to  'Отправить', projects_path, id:'submit_link' %>

<% end %>
```